# Blackview BV9900 - Cannot Unlock Bootloader, Stuck In Fastboot Mode

Tags: adb, rooting, fastboot, bootloader

I've been trying to follow multiple potential guides.
The latest one I've tried is [this one](https://www.androidweblog.com/blackview-bv9900-root-install-twrp-recovery/).

Everything works fine, downloading the Android Platform Tools (adb, fastboot, etc), downloading + updating the USB drivers, etc.

However, the problem starts at trying to boot the phone into fastboot.

Trying to turn the phone off and pressing "Power" + "Volume Up" produces no result.
When connected via USB, you can see the red light flash for a moment, every ~5 sec, but nothing happens.
Trying to run adb reboot bootloader does reboot the phone, but then it gets stuck at a screen with a single `FASTBOOT mode...` writing on the bottom, and the Windows keeps making a "device connected" / "device disconnected" sound in a 5 second cycle.
Trying to run any fastboot command at this point just produces `< waiting for any devices >`.

it should be noted that:

- `adb devices` does recognize the device (already authorized).
- I *can* reach "Factory Mode" (the one with version information and lots of tests) via "Power" + "Volume Up" from a shut-down phone.

Comment: Often you need to manually install the fastboot driver in Windows, so check device manager which device is always disappearing/reappearing.

Comment: I already installed that driver.
And this problem feels like a phone one, as if it's "stuck" or something, especially considering I get different results when using ``adb reboot bootloader`` and trying to use the PWR + VolDown buttons.